# python : list index out of range error while iteratively popping elements

Tags: python, list

I have written a simple python program

```
l=[1,2,3,0,0,1]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
       if l[i]==0:
           l.pop(i)
```

This gives me error 'list index out of range' on line `if l[i]==0:`

After debugging I could figure out that `i` is getting incremented and list is getting reduced.
However, I have loop termination condition `i < len(l)`. Then why I am getting such error?

Comment: "I have loop termination condition i < len(l)"  Why do you say that?  Where in your code do you see that?

Comment: @ S. Lott , i in range(0,len()) means 'i will go upto len(l)-1'

Comment: Another python tip - you could have just written `range(len(l))`, as 0 is the default starting value.

Comment: From PEP 8: *Never use the characters `l` (lowercase letter el), `O` (uppercase letter oh), or `I` (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names.* http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @atv: What makes you think `range(0,len(l))` has a result that varies when `l` is changed?  Why do you think that?  Where did you read it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You are reducing the length of your list `l` as you iterate over it, so as you approach the end of your indices in the range statement, some of those indices are no longer valid.

It *looks* like what you want to do is:

```
l = [x for x in l if x != 0]
```

which will return a copy of `l` without any of the elements that were zero (that operation is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), by the way).  You could even shorten that last part to just `if x`, since non-zero numbers evaluate to `True`.

There is no such thing as a loop termination condition of `i < len(l)`, in the way you've written the code, because `len(l)` is *pre*calculated before the loop, not re-evaluated on each iteration.  You *could* write it in such a way, however:

```
i = 0
while i < len(l):
   if l[i] == 0:
       l.pop(i)
   else:
       i += 1
```

Answer (score 19):

The expression `len(l)` is evaluated only one time, at the moment the `range()` builtin is evaluated. The range object constructed at that time does not change; it can't possibly know anything about the object `l`.

P.S. `l` is a lousy name for a value! It looks like the numeral 1, or the capital letter I.

Answer (score 6):

You're changing the size of the list while iterating over it, which is probably not what you want and is the cause of your error.

**Edit:** As others have answered and commented, list comprehensions are better as a first choice and especially so in response to this question. I offered this as an alternative for that reason, and while not the best answer, it still solves the problem.

So on that note, you could also use `filter`, which allows you to call a function to evaluate the items in the list you don't want.

Example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,0,0,1]
>>> filter(lambda x: x > 0, l)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Live and learn.  Simple is better, except when you need things to be complex.

Comment: You don't even need the lambda, since 0 evaluates to False.  `filter(None, l)`

Comment: @Steve Losh - This is what I love about SO... Learning simple little tricks like that to save me keystrokes in the longrun! Thanks!

Comment: -1: Why do you point a beginner to this legacy way? List comprehensions are now the preferred way to do this.

Comment: -1 for filter or map.  You should always use a list comprehension if it will do the job.

Comment: You guys are right, but `filter` is still an important part of the toolkit for when you need more advanced evaluation.

Answer (score 6):

What [Mark Rushakoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798807/714907) said is true, but if you iterate in the opposite direction, it is possible to remove elements from the list in the for-loop as well. E.g.,

```
x = [1,2,3,0,0,1]
for i in range(len(x)-1, -1, -1):
    if x[i] == 0:
        x.pop(i)
```

It's like a tall building that falls from top to bottom: even if it is in the middle of collapse, you still can "enter" into it and visit yet-to-be-collapsed floors.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to solve this problem is:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1]
while 0 in l:
    l.remove(0)
```

Instead of iterating over list I remove `0` until there aren't any `0` in list

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension will lead you to a solution.

But the right way to copy a object in python is using [python module copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) - Shallow and deep copy operations.

```
l=[1,2,3,0,0,1]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
   if l[i]==0:
       l.pop(i)
```

If instead of this,

```
import copy
l=[1,2,3,0,0,1]
duplicate_l = copy.copy(l)
for i in range(0,len(l)):
   if l[i]==0:
       m.remove(i)
l = m
```

Then, your own code would have worked.
But for optimization, list comprehension is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using python 3.3.5. The above solution of using while loop did not work for me. Even if i put `print (i)` after `len(l)` it gave me an error. I ran the same code in command line (shell)[ window that pops up when we run a function] it runs without error. What i did was calculated len(l) outside the function in main program and passed the length as a parameter. It worked. Python is weird sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you attempted to modify the list you were referencing within the loop that used the list `len()`. When you remove the item from the list, then the new `len()` is calculated on the next loop.

For example, after the first run, when you removed `(i)` using `l.pop(i)`, that happened successfully but on the next loop the length of the list has changed so all index numbers have been shifted. To a certain point the loop attempts to run over a shorted list throwing the error.

Doing this outside the loop works, however it would be better to build and new list by first declaring and empty list before the loop, and later within the loop append everything you want to keep to the new list.

For those of you who may have come to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think most solutions talk here about List Comprehension, but if you'd like to perform in place deletion and keep the space complexity to O(1); The solution is:

```
i = 0
for j in range(len(arr)):
if (arr[j] != 0):
    arr[i] = arr[j]
    i +=1
arr = arr[:i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[]
x = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        print(x[i])
        if(x[i]%5)==0:
            del x[i]
        else:
            i += 1
print(*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
while True:
        n += 1
        try:
          DATA[n]['message']['text']
        except:
          key = DATA[n-1]['message']['text']
          break
```

Console :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botnet.py", line 82, in <module>
    key =DATA[n-1]['message']['text']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I recently had a similar problem and I found that I need to decrease the list index by one.

So instead of:

```
if l[i]==0:
```

You can try:

```
if l[i-1]==0:
```

Because the list indices start at 0 and your range will go just one above that.

Comment: Not only is this wrong, it's addressing a different problem. OP has an issue where they themselves are removing elements of the list as they iterate over the list. Also, `i` starts at `0` in OP's question. Your example would have OP start iterating at the last element of the array, and then wrapping back around into the first.

Comment: Try this (since this is a comment, you're on your own to figure out the formatting in your IDE):

```python
l=[1,2,3,0,0,1]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    print("element:" + str(i - 1))
    print(l[i-1])
```