# For loop with embedded if statement list index out of range

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following python code:

```
raw_list = reminders_context['data']['reminder_list']
```

This statement works fine and gets the required info that I want.

The following code gives me the error list index out of range but the inner workings of the for loop for eg.[I obviously substitute the 'i' value for a number, then get the first 10 characters of the list item with [:10]], work fine when I set a trace in pdb mode.

```
raw_list[i]['created'][:10] == raw_list[i + 1]['created'][:10]
```

Code that gives an error:

```
for i in range(len(raw_list)):
    if raw_list[i]['created'][:10] == raw_list[i + 1]['created'][:10]:
        del raw_list[i + 1]
    else:
        pass
```

How can I change it so that I do not get the error?

I have seen something about how my list gets reduced in the for loop when iterating but I simply do not know how to implement it in my code.

The article I'm referring to is here:

[python : list index out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798796/python-list-index-out-of-range-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing:

```
for i in range(len(raw_list)):
```

into:

```
for i in range(len(raw_list)-1):
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(n)` goes from 0 to n-1. In this case, n-1 is the last valid index in your list. When your loop is on the iteration `i = len(raw_list)-1` (the last iteration), your operation to access the `i+1`th element tries to access `len(raw_list)` which is not a valid index in the array. So the last valid iteration your loop can do is `i=len(rawlist)-2`

Basically, you need to make your for loop do one less iteration.