# for loops in Python: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python. I have to write a for loop. For example, there are 2 files, say "files". I need to extract the data from each. My codes are below, however, it keeps giving me the error:

> list assignment index out of range.

I've searched for existing answers, but sorry I don't understand how to apply to my case. Many Thanks.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = []
for i in range(0,2):
       ds[i] = xr.open_dataset(files[i])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python : list index out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798796/python-list-index-out-of-range-error)

Comment: Just do `for file in files: ds.append(xr.open_dataset(file))`, you don't need to use indices at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
ds = []
for file in files: 
    ds.append(xr.open_dataset(file))
```

You don't need to use indices at all.

Even shorter and cleaner, as you are building a list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
ds = [xr.open_dataset(file) for file in files]
```

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing (My 1st day in Python!)

Answer (score 1):

You’ve two ways to achieve this viz `append` and `insert`.
`append` is used to add the content at the end of the list while `insert` can insert the element at any location of the list.
As of now, you’re trying to add some element to the Blank list, so `append` is a good option. 
Best answer for your question is:

```
for file in files: 
    ds.append(xr.open_dataset(file))
```

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing (My 1st day in Python!)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use lists indexed, like in C. Just use `append()`. Also, you need to declare the `files` list too, where you store the files. And you can call the `range` method with the length of `files` list.

> Method 1, with index and classic `for` loop:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = []
for i in range(len(files)):
       ds.append(xr.open_dataset(files[i]))
```

> Method 2, without index and `for each` loop:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = []
for file in files:
       ds.append(xr.open_dataset(file))
```

> Method 3, with `list comprehension`:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = [xr.open_dataset(file) for file in files]
```

Comment: It worked, I also succeeded in adding a following step into the loops, based on your example. Many thanks. Sincerely.