# How to Fix "List Index out of range" in python?

Tags: python, list, iteration

```
#function description   
 def getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b):
        q = []
        for i in range(len(keyboards)):
            for j in range(len(drives)):
                q.append(keyboards[i] + drives[j]) 
        for m in range(len(q)):
            if(q[m] > b):
                q.remove(q[m])
            else:
                pass
        if q is not None:
            return max(q)
        else:
            return -1
```

And the error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Solution.py", line 42, in <module>
        moneySpent = getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b)
    File "Solution.py", line 15, in getMoneySpent
        if(q[m] > b):
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

keeps on getting this error message.This is a problem in hackerrank i will link that below for anybody who wants further reference:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/electronics-shop/problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python : list index out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798796/python-list-index-out-of-range-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
def getMoneySpent(keyboards, drives, b):
    q = []
    for k in keyboards :
        for d in drives :
            price = k + d
            if price <= b :
                q.append(price) 

    return max(q) if q else -1
```

Instead of removing elements, just don't add them in the first place...

Comment: This is Accurate.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `q.remove(q[m])`, you are removing items from a list while you are iterating over it.

one solution is you save all desired `m`s to be removed in another list and delete them after the loop finished.

or

You can look at these links to get better clue:

[How to delete list items while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

[Another link](https://codippa.com/how-to-remove-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python/)

You can understand this:

```
q[:] = [i for i in q if i <= b]
```

put this line instead of your for loop over q.

Also note that:

```
else:
    pass
```

is redundant, you can remove.