# Why does this code return 'pop index out of range'?

Tags: python

I've tried to understand the logic and process that causes this, but still don't understand why it's happening. Sorry if it's a really simple/bad question.

**This is the question:**

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.

**This is the code with error:**

```py
def sum67(nums):
  ans = 0


  if len(nums) == 0:
    return 0 


  elif 6 not in nums:
    for val in nums:
      ans += val
    return ans  

  elif 6 in nums:
    x = nums.index(6)
    y = nums.index(7, x)
    for i in range(x, y):
      nums.pop(i)

  for val in nums:
    ans += val

  return ans
```

**This is the error:**

```
pop index out of range
```

Comment: You are popping/removing elements from the list while iterating which will cause an error eventually since the indices you expected from the beginning are not valid anymore from 2nd+ iteration.

Comment: We love that you're here and we need code we can debug for you. The screen snip you provided can't be executed.

Comment: For future reference, your question was most likely closed because you posted the code as an image instead of text.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Try printing `i` and `nums` right before you `pop`, and you'll see that the original range won't match the element indices anymore. See [python : list index out of range error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798796/2745495).

Comment: Learning [how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) will help you with this and with many other problems.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I've learnt a lot already, from debuggers, to the solution to my problem, and even how to post correctly. Happy to be here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woohoo! I just learnt about the `del` function.

My solution was to replace:

```
elif 6 in nums:
  x = nums.index(6)
  y = nums.index(7, x)
  for i in range(x, y):
    nums.pop(i)`
```

with:

```
while 6 in nums:
  x = nums.index(6)
  y = nums.index(7, x)
  del nums[x:y+1]
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the help, especially @NewPythonUser!